# How to align text inside table thead to center horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one question how can I align my text inside thead to center horizontally and vertically[image: Table]

```
<table id="stanari" class="table table-striped table-bordered w-100 animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name and last name of tenants</th>
            <th>Cell phone of tenants</th>
            <th>Apartment address</th>
            <th>Number at the door of the apartment</th>
            <th>Paid deposit in euros</th>
            <th>Date of tenants registration</th>
            <th>Monthly rent in euros</th>
            <th>Is the monthly rent paid</th>
            <th>Payment date</th>
            <th>For month</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: did you try vertical-align:middle ?

Comment: I tried but nothing happens

Comment: on the th elements?

Comment: Yes, I tried first on tr then on th and lastly on thead but nothing changes

Comment: Have you tried the built in bootstrap class `align-middle` for the table cells you wish to align?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the bootstrap class `align-middle` and `text-center` to the `th` elements.

[Bootstrap Vertical alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/) also [Bootstrap Text alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/)

```css
th:nth-of-type(1),
th:nth-of-type(4),
th:nth-of-type(5),
th:nth-of-type(8){
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="stanari" class="table table-striped table-bordered w-100 animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="align-middle text-center">First name and last name of tenants</th>
            <th class="align-middle text-center">Cell phone of tenants</th>
            <th class="align-middle text-center">Apartment address</th>
            <th class="align-middle text-center">Number at the door of the apartment</th>
            <th class="align-middle text-center">Paid deposit in euros</th>
            <th class="align-middle text-center">Date of tenants registration</th>
            <th class="align-middle text-center">Monthly rent in euros</th>
            <th class="align-middle text-center">Is the monthly rent paid</th>
            <th class="align-middle text-center">Payment date</th>
            <th class="align-middle text-center">For month</th>
            <th class="align-middle text-center"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="align-middle text-center col-3">John and Jane Doe</td>
            <td class="align-middle text-center">555-555-5555</td>
            <td class="align-middle text-center">5555 Someroad streer</td>
            <td class="align-middle text-center">555</td>
            <td class="align-middle text-center">1555 Euro</td>
            <td class="align-middle text-center">5-5-21</td>
            <td class="align-middle text-center">2555 Euro</td>
            <td class="align-middle text-center">Paid in full</td>
            <td class="align-middle text-center">5-1-21</td>
            <td class="align-middle text-center">May</td>
            <td class="align-middle text-center">N/A</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That slove my problem with vertically align thanks, but why my first name and last name still look like ugly I set width to 100% but nothing changes

Comment: What d you mean by ugly? Do you want it to take up more space?

Comment: You can set the ***width*** of the exact TH element using `min-width`, see my update

Answer (score 0):

by default th tags should be aligned center vertically, so you've something overides the default behavior which i recommend you to fix.

however, you can still fix this issue by css like the following:

```
th {
 display:flex,
 align-items:center,
}
```

Comment: I use datatabels and bootstrap and idk why this is happening

Comment: Yeah, this is default behaviour. It would seem that you have an override which is aligning to top.